# SSAS 2008R2 MDX Script

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a problem with a mdx script ,I'm trying to aggregate two sets using the SUM function

Basically, I have 2 calculated member that will give me my date range window

Members in mdx script are as follow :

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[NumberOfWeeksInPeriodLY] AS 
   COUNT(DESCENDANTS([Date].[Retail Calendar].CurrentMember.Lag(2),3),INCLUDEEMPTY)-1;
// This one will give me 15

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[StartingWeekLY] AS 
  (DESCENDANTS([Date].[Retail Calendar].CurrentMember.Lag(2),3)).Item(0).Member_Key;  
//This one will give me 130;

CREATE  MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[EndingWeekLY] AS 
    Cint([Measures].[StartingWeekLY]+[Measures].[NumberOfWeeksInPeriodLY]); //This will give me 145
```

What Im Trying to do with this is:

within the MDX script I have:

```
SCOPE([Date].[Retail Calendar].[Retail Semester].MEMBERS);

     [Date Analysis - Retail Calendar].[Test53Weeks] =
      SUM(
        {
           (
             DESCENDANTS
             (
               [Date].[Retail Calendar].CurrentMember,3
             )
            .Item(1).Lag(53) 
           )

   :
       [Date].[Retail Calendar].[Retail Week].**Item([Measures].[EndingWeekLY]))**

    }
      ,[Date Analysis - Retail Calendar].[Current Time Period]
  );

END SCOPE;
```

If I hardcode the value on [Date].[Retail Calendar].[Retail Week].Item(145)
 it work, i got the correct aggregation however,

If I use `[Date].[Retail Calendar].[Retail Week].Item([Measures].[EndingWeekLY]))`
it does not work, even if the calculated member `([Measures].[EndingWeekLY])`
contain indeed the value of 145, I got the whole level aggragated instead ...

So far I have tryed StrToMember,strToTuple,StrToSet functions, I have also tried explicitly to cast to int (CInt(([Measures].[EndingWeekLY])) same result...

any thought as of what the hek is wrong?

Thanks

Rick